# Google Calendar API: How to create/edit/delete events without Google password?

Tags: java, oauth, google-calendar-api

I have an application, which reads/edits/deletes events in Google Calendar.

Now it is necessary to enter Google user name and password for doing this.

However, this is a problem: Many users are afraid of giving away the password.

Question: Is there a way to get access to the events in Google Calendar **without** asking the user for his/her Google password (i. e. via OAuth) ?

Thanks in advance

Dmitri

P. S.: The appication is written in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it, but there's an api for using oauth on google apps, including the calendar:  http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth.html

It appears to be pretty well explained here: http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/oauth.html