# How to add event on other user calendar without being logged in

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am stuck on Google Calendar API on Add event.

I want to allow other users to add event on Google Calendar without being logged in.
So far not finding any success. I can get calendar for user but not finding proper solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to check this out:

[Google Calendar API: How to create/edit/delete events without Google password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282162/google-calendar-api-how-to-create-edit-delete-events-without-google-password)

This is basically a way to add an event without beeing logged in, or asking for the users credentials.

Comment: Thanks.. I gone through this.. but still not sure that google allow to do that or not.. Even on your provided link they are not sure for this..

Comment: Thanks.. It worked.. we can create event on someone else google calendar without being looged in ..
1. Make that user calendar public
2. You need to pass authentication with that.. It worked for me..